# How to launch the symbolicatecrash in sdk4.0?

Tags: iphone

how to launch symbolicatecrash from Xcode?

I have a crash file with the address, I want transfer the address into symbol which are in my source code.

When using gdb, we can do  that gdb ./yourApplication coredumpfile.
I think xcode should have a similar tool for transfer the address into symbols.

Comment: What is symbolicatecrash? Do you have a link or anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've detailed how to use symbolicatecrash in one of my blog posts. To summarize, you can find the script at the following location:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash
```

Then you execute the script using the following command:

```
./symbolicatecrash.sh -A -v [crashlog-filename] MyApp.dSYM
```

Make sure that both, your Symbol file (MyApp.dSYM) and your App binary (MyApp) are both stored in the directory in which you're executing symbolicate crash. For more details, have a look at the full blog post here: http://apptech.next-munich.com/2010/01/symbolicatecrash.html

Answer (score 0):

Note if you try to symbolicate crash, you have to 3 file in a same folder (.app, .dSYM and .crash), and then the importance is make sure the .app and .dSYM file is the lastest file of your app build